# Excel VBA - Click on web element while the page is loading?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation

I'm wondering if it is possible to click on a web element while the page is loading, here is my code, but it's not working:

```
Sub Link()

       Dim IE                  As InternetExplorer
       Dim lMaterial           As String
       Dim lObra               As String
       Dim Shell As Object
       'Dim IE As Object


       'ABRE O IE EXPANDIDO
       Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
       IE.Visible = 1
       IE.Toolbar = 0
       IE.MenuBar = 0

       'ABRE O SIENGE
       IE.Navigate "https://curyempreendimentos.sienge.com.br/sienge/MED/listLiberacoesMedicoes.do"
       'IDENTIFICA SE O SIENGE FOI TOTALMENTE CARREGADO
       Do While IE.Busy = True
           DoEvents
       Loop
       'IDENTIFICA SE O SIENGE FOI TOTALMENTE CARREGADO
       While IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
       Wend
       sng = timer
           Do While sng + 1 > timer
           Loop

       'INFORMA O Nº DO CONTRATO
       IE.Document.all("labelContrato").Value = ActiveCell
       Call IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript("javascript: CT_BLR(this);onChangeContrato(false)", "JavaScript")

       'CONSULTA MEDIÇÕES À SEREM LIBERADAS

       Do While IE.Busy = True

       Set elems = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
           For Each e In elems
               If (e.getAttribute("Value") = "Consultar") Then
                   e.Click
               Exit For
           End If
       Next e

       Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: you need to wait until it loads. `Do: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.Busy <> "True"`. Is one one way to do it. If you search google, you'll find more ways.

Comment: what does not working mean? And what are you trying to click on and what should be the outcome of the click? And are you logging in?

Comment: "while the page is loading" is a bit vague - why specifically this and not wait for the page to finish loading?  If you don't wait for it to complete then there's no way of predicting what effect your clicks might have: scripts etc may not be full loaded even if an element is there to be clicked.

Comment: Tim, This is a ERP that I use on my Work, so I have to be logged. Actually my code works fine If I wait for page finish loading. After the page loads I do have to click on a button witch liberate a "flag" and I want to able to click on it first then my co-workers. I realise that while I'm surfirng on a web I can click on a button even if the page is not fully loaded. So, that's what I want to do.

Comment: It is better to wait for the page to get loaded completely. From your last comment, I understand that your goal is to click before any other worker click on it. As per my understanding. There should not be a noticeable delay if you wait for the page to get loaded completely and automated click will be faster than manual click of other co worker.